# Nginx ingress is not resolving path properly for kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, prometheus, nginx-ingress

I created simple kubernetes cluster with demo app.
When creating the cluster I installed prometheus-stack and nginx-ingress-controller with helm (default values files).

After the cluster is set up I create Ingress object to expose prometheus, grafana and alertmanager with:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: monitoring-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-operated
            port:
              number: 9090
      - path: /alertmanager(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-stack-kube-prom-alertmanager
            port:
              number: 9093
      - path: /grafana(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-stack-grafana
            port:
              number: 80
```

When I try to access prometheus via `<ingress-controller's external IP>/prometheus` it resolves to `<ingress-controller's external IP>/graph` and displays 404 - page not found.

If I use for example `kubectl port-forward svc/prometheus-operated 9090:9090 -n monitoring` I can reach prometheus without problem.

I can reach alertmanager through `<ingress-controller's external IP>/alertmanager`. The path is resolved to `<ingress-controller's external IP>/alertmanager/#/alerts`

I suspect there is something wrong with the path rewriting but can't figure out what.

Please help...

Comment: Hello @Artek. Please change `$1` to `$2` in your `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:` and let me know about the results.

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor, I changed $1 to $2, the status after the change is that i can reach alertmanager when typing <external IP>/alertmanager but I can't reach grafana and prometheus. What I noticed is that when typing `<external IP>/prometheus` it resolves to `<external IP>/graph` (for grafana /login) as it should because that is the "home page" of prometheus but then displays 404 or just white screen.

Comment: Hello @Artek. Thanks for the feedback. In that case I recommend a different approach. It would be easier and less prone to mistakes if you divide your Ingress into three separate ones. One for each rewrite rule you'd like to have, so one for Prometheus, one for Grafana and one for Alertmanager. Your Ingress Controller will handle that. Could you please try it?

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor, thanks for suggestion. I split the ingress to 3 parts, one for prometheus, one for grafana and one for alertmanager. However the result is still the same as using one big ingress before. I kept the `rewrite-target: /$2` in all ingresses. Sidenote, I don't really understand how the `rewrite-target: /$2``works, if you have some good resources to explain this mechanism I would appreciate (I did read [nginx docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) but it is still not clear for me)

Comment: I see. Could you please provide the exact endpoints you'd like to reach for each rewrite? And as for the resources, I am afraid that the official rewrite guide you linked is the best we got.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor eventually I was able to figure it out. Thanks anyway for your time and effort! I will answer my question later in the day and you are welcome to evaluate it. Have a great day!

Comment: @Artek can you please post the solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I was able to find 2 solutions to this problem.

**Option 1**

I had DNS zone in azure (where my cluster lives as well) and there I added subdomains for grafana, prometheus and alertmanager pointing to the ingress-controller external IP.

When deploying kube-prometheus-stack with Helm Chart I provided default root path for prometheus in values.yaml file with folowing configuration:

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    externalUrl: http://prometheus.mydomainname.something
```

The Ingress manifest for (for example Prometheus) then needs to include the host address and contain only root path "/".

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-new
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: prometheus.mydomainname.something
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-stack-kube-prom-prometheus
            port:
              number: 9090
```

**Option 2**

You can also provide default paths for each of the applications from kube-prometheus-stack (prometheus, grafana, alertmanager) as:

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    externalUrl: http://mydomainname.something/prometheus
```

and make Ingress manifest to redirect based on the path with:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-new
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /prometheus
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-stack-kube-prom-prometheus
            port:
              number: 9090
```